# while debugging python in visual studio auto window don't show anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, debugging

while debugging python my auto window is not showing anyvalue as shown as the following screenshot:
[image: I think the value of x, y and sum should be appear in the auto window]

I think the value of x, y and sum should be appear in the auto window

Comment: also: do not post pictures of code, post the code itself - nicely formatted ([read here why](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) ). Please do not call variables after build-ins .. `sum()` being one of them - you shadow it

Comment: [MS Info about the Autos-Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows#bkmk_whatvariables)  - it shows different things for different languages. the whole page does not mention python at all, so its probably not yet supported. You could file it as _bug_ / suggestion to VS Developer teams? There is a (VS 2017) small icon on the top rioght corner next to the QuickLaunch field to report problems. Nobody here is able to fix it for you ...

Comment: auto values are supported in python. please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-python-in-visual-studio

Comment: It seems the other documentation is not up to snuff. At least yours shows a picture of Auto working. What do you try to accomplish by posting here? SO is not Microsoft VS. We can not change how VS works. We are no bugtracker for VS nor are we a channel to ask smth from MS VS team. You can use the button in the top right corner for suggestions to its team. The yellow flag also tells me you are not up-to-date, so try updating. Chances are, your version of VS does not yet support it as the text you cited has a date of 2018-07-13...

Comment: Same here - you might want to file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> while debugging python in visual studio auto window don't show anything

According to the [Autos and Locals Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx):

The Autos window **displays variables used around the current line** (the place where the debugger is stopped). **Exactly which variables displayed is different in different languages**.

In Python the Autos window displays the variables used at least **two lines before** the current line (the line at which execution is stopped).

In your code, you set the Breakpoints on the first line of the variables `x=10`, there is no any other variables before this Breakpoints, that is the reason why visual studio auto window don't show anything.

To resolve this issue, you just need to move the Breakpoints to the second line `y=5`, then you get it work:

[image]

Hope this helps.